# Count same values in mysql query

Tags: mysql

So i have a query like

```
SELECT * FROM `catalog` WHERE `id` IN ('2','2','3','3','3');
```

And this return only 2 rows with id 2 and 3. It is possible make it return 5 rows (2 with id "2" and 3 with id "3") or add count as new column?

Comment: You're using a database engine to retrieve redundant data, for god sakes why?

Comment: This is more than a little strange. ID is normally the primary key of a table, which means that you only have _one_. How do you expect to get multiple and why would you want to? Secondly, you're quoting numbers. Please don't do that unless they're stored in a character data-type. Please don't do that.

Comment: @Ben Yes, ID is primary. I need to get all rows with ID from array, what look like "2,2,3,3,3", and add count of same ID in this array.

Comment: seems you want to join with your array... lol

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you would want to do something like this, but instead of using an 'in' clause you could use an inner query:

```
select *
from `catalog` c,
(
    select 2 ids
    union all
    select 2
    union all
    select 3
    union all
    select 3
    union all
    select 3
) k
where c.id = k.ids
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT t.p,count(*)  FROM 
    catalog, 
    (SELECT 2 as id
    Union all select 2 as id
    Union all select 3 as id
    Union all select 3 as id
    Union all select 3 as id)as t 
where catalog.id = t.id
```

Comment: This is identical to AW101's answer

Comment: Yes, it's true, while I was testing my solution, there wasn't yet AW101 answer and I posted it.

Comment: Exactly the same has happened to me before ;) Great minds think alike, +1

Answer (score 0):

It can be done using temporary tables:

```
create temporary table arrayt (id int);
insert into arrayt values  ('2'),('2'),('3'),('3'),('3');
select catalog.* from arrayt a LEFT JOIN catalog on (a.id=catalog.id);
```

if you need  count

```
select count(catalog.id) as count,catalog.id as id from arrayt a LEFT JOIN catalog on (a.id=catalog.id) group by catalog.id;
```